# Google Cloud Save with JavaScript/REST getting 409 Conflict

Tags: javascript, rest, save, cloud

So I'm trying to implement the google appstate cloud save feature to save a string (https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/states) but I am getting a 409 conflict error. I must be using it incorrectly. Does anyone have any examples of a JavaScript implementation?
This is how I am going about it:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/appstate/v1/states
```

returns:

```
{
 "kind": "appstate#listResponse",
 "maximumKeyCount": 4,
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "appstate#getResponse",
   "stateKey": 0,
   "currentStateVersion": "CNDVopDDwLgC"
  }
 ]
}
```

then I

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/appstate/v1/states/0
```

with body:

```
{

currentVersion: "CNDVopDDwLgC"
data: "some data"
kind: "appstate#updateRequest"

}
```

which gives the error: 409 Conflict

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "OutOfDateVersion",
    "message": "The resource version you are attempting to modify does not match the current version on the server."
   }
  ],
  "code": 409,
  "message": "The resource version you are attempting to modify does not match the current version on the server."
 }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?